# How to open multiple socket streams on the same runloop in iOS, possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sockets, networking

In my program, I have a read and write stream scheduled on the runloop and that's working fine.  Later on in the program I want to open another stream either read or write depends on the role then I want to schedule it to the same runloop to the same server, but that's not working. I called open on the newly created stream, but I don't see any NSStreamEventOpenCompleted event coming to the newly opened stream.  Here's how I create the streams and the implementation of the delegate to handle the events:

controller.m

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication:(NSString *)ip_address withPort:(NSInteger)port role:(network_role_t)role
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    NSLog(@"server IP: %@, port: %d, role: %d", ip_address, port, role);
    if (port != 8080) {
        if (role == HOST) {
            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)ip_address, port, NULL, &writeStream);
            imageOutStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
            [imageOutStream setDelegate:self];
            [imageOutStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [imageOutStream open];
            NSLog(@"host connected");
        } else if (role == CLIENT) {
            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)ip_address, port, &readStream, NULL);
            imageInStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
            [imageInStream setDelegate:self];
            [imageInStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [imageInStream open];
            NSLog(@"client connected");
        }
    } else {
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)ip_address, port, &readStream, &writeStream);
        inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
        outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
        [inputStream setDelegate:self];
        [outputStream setDelegate:self];
        [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [inputStream open];
        [outputStream open];
    }
}
```

delegate implementation:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent 
{

    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (theStream == inputStream) {
                /* send regular data */
            } else if (theStream == imageInStream) {
                /* send raw data */
            }
        break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            if (theStream == imageOutStream) {
                NSLog(@"imageOutStream opened");
            } else if (theStream == imageInStream) {
                NSLog(@"imageInStream opened");
            }
        break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            //NSError *theError = [theStream streamError];
            NSLog(@"Socket error string: %@", [[theStream streamError] localizedDescription]);
        break;
    }
}
```

So I don't see imageOutStream opened and imageInStream opened printed out when they are connected to the server.  What I found out is in the scheduleInRunLoop: for imageInStream and imageOutStream if I use mainRunLoop instead of currentRunLoop, I can see the stream opened print out, but even with that the send and receive still got problem.  Am I doing something wrong in scheduling the streams? Or do I have to use other method other than scheduleInRunLoop if I want to create multiple socket streams.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd add unconditional logging at the top of -stream:handleEvent: like `NSLog(@"stream %@ got event %x", theStream, (unsigned)streamEvent);`. This will tell you if you're getting events you're not handling, which I suspect you (sort of) are.

In the [NSStream docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001981-SW1),

> **Stream Event Constants**
>
> One or more of these constants may be sent to the delegate as a bit field in the second parameter of stream:handleEvent:.

If it's a bitfield, you can't easily switch on. It might be 3 (`NSStreamEventOpenCompleted|NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable`) which means the stream has opened *and* there's data available for reading.

The easy fix looks something like this

```
if (streamEvent&NSStreamEventOpenCompleted) {
  ...
}

if (streamEvent&NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable) {
  ...
}

...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. it turns out i was calling the initNetworkCommunication from another thread, so it was using the thread's runloop.  I changed to mainRunLoop and the thing was working.